# Can anyone help me with a header / title problem in which I must use only HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, typography

[image: ExampleImage]

I'm currently trying to mimic a mockup and I am having trouble designing the top portion of this website. The Lorem Ipsum seems as if its in a container with everything else where its evenly distributed. I'm unsure how to put these titles as well as paragraph in a container as shown in the picture in which it will eventually be responsive. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to show us the code that is giving you trouble. And as a comment it is worth thinking about the semantics of what you are setting particularly to help those using assistive devices e.g. screen readers. Is the red a main title - perhaps set as an h1 element and so on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you somewhat idea of how to deal with such requirements. I have added an example. Make sure you change all the font face, font size, spacing, element placement, etc properties as per your requirement.

```css
  .banner {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-height: 450px;
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/3575282/pexels-photo-3575282.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2) no-repeat 50% 50% / cover;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}

.content .title {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 2.2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content .subTitle {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content .sentence {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="subTitle">Dolar sit amet aran</div>
      <div class="sentence">Rerum quas delectus non ab eveniet nihil, eaque tempora incidunt blanditiis, molestias sit,
        unde id? Tempora eius illo labore officiis quis quae.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. Looking at the code, it makes a lot of sense on how you approached this.